# Intent.getBooleanExtra always returns true

Tags: android

Whether I click on Save or on Cancel, "savedDate" is always false. Any idea how to fix it?

I have researched a lot on this topic. But nothing fixed my issue :(. Also, first MainActivity starts AnotherActivity and in onClick, AnotherActivity starts MainActivity .

**AnotherActivity.java:**

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        switch (view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.SaveButton:
            {
                savedDate = true;
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("savedDate", true);
                startActivity(intent);
               //m.HighlightCalendar();
            }
            case R.id.CancelButton:
            {
                savedDate = false;
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("savedDate", false);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        intent = getIntent();
        // get my boolean from save button
        savedDate = intent.getBooleanExtra("savedDate", true); // this code is not getting the boolean from Another Activity
        // if i pressed my saved button
        if(savedDate) {
            //add date
            DateList.add(selectDate);
            for (int i = 0; i < DateList.size(); i++) {
                events.add(DateList.get(i));
                //update my calendar
                calendarview.updateCalendar(events);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hm. Try to run in the debug mode and verify that all the values are what you think they are by putting good breakpoints.

Comment: Did that so many times. In onClick it sets it to either 'true' or 'false' based on what button I click on. But in MainActivity, the boolean is always true.

Comment: I'm assuming that because of the default value provided here : `savedDate = intent.getBooleanExtra("savedDate", true);` Change to false to verify. If that seems to be it, try and copy the same code to `onCreate` as well and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll start with some assumptions of what you did in the code you didn't post. These are actually all based on the fact, that you process the intent extras in `onResume()`.

From the `MainActivity` you start the `AnotherActivity` to perform some action. So when you go to `MainActivity` from `AnotherActivity` you'll start the already created `MainActivity`. In this case `getIntent()` just returns the original intent used to create the activity without `savedDate` set.

If your configuration allows it, you could use [`onNewIntent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent))

> Note that `getIntent()` still returns the original Intent. You can use `setIntent(Intent)` to update it to this new Intent.

But even better would be using [`startActivityForResult()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) and do `setResult(RESULT_OK)` or `setResult(RESULT_CANCELED)` and `finish()` instead of starting a new activity with a new intent in `onClick()`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Also, I realised that I hadn't put break in the case blocks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are not using the switch case correctly. You are missing a `break;` from the end of the first case and hence it executes the body of the second case statement.

Comment: This is true and will improve the code but I think it is not the answer.  The intent data needs to be updated as described in a few other answers.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras.
```

and then:

```
boolean value = bundle.getBoolen("savedData");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: tried it. Resulted in a null pointer exception.

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Bundle.getBoolean(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 0):

@tynn has the heart of the problem: your call to getIntent in onResume merely returns the the initial intent used to start your activity the first time around.

While I agree that startActivityForResult is one way to go, another is to override onNewIntent in MainActivity and put your logic for handling the button into that method:

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
   savedDate = intent.getBooleanExtra("savedDate", true); // this code is not getting the boolean from Another Activity
    // if i pressed my saved button
    if(savedDate) {
        //add date
        DateList.add(selectDate);
        for (int i = 0; i < DateList.size(); i++) {
            events.add(DateList.get(i));
            //update my calendar
            calendarview.updateCalendar(events);
        }
    }
```

This is a little bit simpler and most likely accomplishes what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Add `break` in switch cases.

```
case R.id.SaveButton:
            {
                savedDate = true;
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                intent1.putExtra("savedDate", true);
                startActivity(intent1);
               //m.HighlightCalendar();
                break;
            }
            case R.id.CancelButton:
            {
                savedDate = false;
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                intent2.putExtra("savedDate", false);
                startActivity(intent2);
                braek;
            }
```

And get the boolean value in MainActivity like this..

```
Boolean savedDate = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("savedDate");
```

Hope it helps.